# DOM elements inside jQuery DataTable cannot be updated

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#checkall', function() {
            console.log($("#checkall").is(':checked'));

                    if($("#checkall").is(':checked')) {

                        $("#checkall").iCheck('uncheck');
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#checkall").iCheck('check');
                    }
           });
```

I have a checkbox inside the table header (I want to make a checkall checkbox) and when I click the checkbox gets checked, but when I double click it it doesn't get unchecked and returns false every time as if the DOM cannot get updated when it's inside a DataTable. Is there a way to retain the state and allow the checkbox to retain it's state? Without the above function, I can't even check it, it doesn't respond.

I know it has to do with the state, because I can uncheck and check the checkbox with iCheck('uncheck') and iCheck('check') on the Firefox console.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with your HTML so we can test it.

Comment: Try if($("#checkall").is(':checked')) {$(this).prop('checked', true);} else {$(this).prop('checked', false);}